# Executing existing Python Code in Azure ML

Tags: python-2.7, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a code written Python and I need to deploy it on Azure ML. The python code consists of many function and returns the output in Jason format.

However when implemented on Azure ML, there are no errors. But, there is no result as such generated. It is displaying the input dataset for both Result Dataset and Python device dataset.

Can I know, how to go about it. I'm new to Azure ML, and have no clue how to go about it

Comment: Can you please add the code you want to have on AzureML?

Comment: Seconding a request for the code. My suspicion is that you need to modify your `azureml_main()` function to return a pandas dataframe containing the JSON output.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-python-data-access

There is everything explained in detail in the link above. Look at sections:
1)How to install the Azure Machine Learning Python client library
2)Access datasets from a local Python application

In fact, I didn't try it by myself. But I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Answers should be more than a link to documentation. They should be detailed enough to stand on their own even if, for example, the link later becomes broken. An answer should be enough information to completely resolve the question being asked.